# How to darken a background using CSS?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have an element with text in it. Whenever I decrease the opacity, then I decrease the opacity of the WHOLE body. Is there any way I can just make the `background-image` darker, and not everything else?

```
background-image:url('http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/274/6/f/ocean__sky__stars__and_you_by_muddymelly-d4bg1ub.png');
```

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Just add this code to your image css

```css
 body{
 background:
        /* top, transparent black, faked with gradient */ 
        linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
        ),
        /* bottom, image */
        url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614030424754-24d0eebd46b2);
    }
```

Reference: [linear-gradient() - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

UPDATE: Not all browsers support RGBa, so you should have a 'fallback color'. This color will be most likely be solid (fully opaque) ex:`background:rgb(96, 96, 96)`. Refer to this [blog](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for RGBa browser support.

UPDATE 2023: All modern browsers now supports RGBa :
[caniuse link](https://caniuse.com/?search=rgba())

Comment: Any cross browser issues with this?

Comment: what is the property if we want to specify separately background-image and this?

Comment: @Petruza it seems that we have no choice but use this syntax. Read the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient): _"Because <gradient>s belong to the <image> data type, they can only be used where <image>s can be used. For this reason, linear-gradient() won't work on background-color and other properties that use the <color> data type"_

Answer (score 30):

Setting `background-blend-mode` to `darken` would be the most direct and shortest way to achieve the purpose however you must set a `background-color` first for the blend mode to work.
This is also the best way if you need to manipulate the values in javascript later on.

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65) url('http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/274/6/f/ocean__sky__stars__and_you_by_muddymelly-d4bg1ub.png');
background-blend-mode: darken;
```

[Can I use for background-blend](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode)

Comment: edge or IE11 is not really a browser

Comment: Actually, this is the best answer, but if we don't want to touch background image url declaration (like `background` or `background-image`), this is perfect: `background-color: #0005; background-blend-mode: darken;`

Answer (score 26):

when you want to brightness or darker of background-color, you can use this css code

```
.brighter-span {
  filter: brightness(150%);
}

.darker-span {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about css [filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/). In case it helps someone, here's [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) status (March, 2020).

Comment: Note that this will brighten/darken everything (including text) inside of the element with these classes.

Answer (score 22):

Use an :after psuedo-element:

```
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.overlay:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.overlay:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Check out my pen >

http://codepen.io/craigocurtis/pen/KzXYad

Comment: Good but not working in Firefox 47.0.1 on windows 10. But works with IE. Do you have any fix for firefox ?

Comment: @JohnMax Firefox is working fine now. Just have to wait a few years.

Answer (score 8):

It might be possible to do this with `box-shadow`

*however, I can't get it to actually apply to an image. Only on solid color backgrounds*

```css
body {
  background: #131418;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.mycooldiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.red {
  background: red
}
.blue {
  background: blue
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow
}
.green {
  background: green
}
#darken {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 400px 110px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  /*darkness level control - change the alpha value for the color for darken/ligheter effect */
}
```

```html
Red
<div class="mycooldiv red"></div>
Darkened Red
<div class="mycooldiv red" id="darken"></div>
Blue
<div class="mycooldiv blue"></div>
Darkened Blue
<div class="mycooldiv blue" id="darken"></div>
Yellow
<div class="mycooldiv yellow"></div>
Darkened Yellow
<div class="mycooldiv yellow" id="darken"></div>
Green
<div class="mycooldiv green"></div>
Darkened Green
<div class="mycooldiv green" id="darken"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `backdrop-filter: brightness(50%);`

Warning:

- "Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent".
- Unfortunately for firefox, this requires at this time: User must explicitly enable the feature

Answer (score 2):

You can use a container for your background, placed as absolute and negative z-index :
http://jsfiddle.net/2YW7g/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="bg">         
    </div>
    Hello World!!!!
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    color:red;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size:18px;
}
.main .bg{
    position:absolute;
      width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-image:url("http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/274/6/f/ocean__sky__stars__and_you_by_muddymelly-d4bg1ub.png");
    z-index:-1;
}

.main:hover .bg{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what's already here, use the following:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7),rgba(0,0,0,.7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7),rgba(0,0,0,.7));
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7),rgba(0,0,0,.7));
filter: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b3000000', endColorstr='#b3000000',GradientType=0 )");
```

...for cross-browser support of a 70% linear-gradient overlay. To brighten the image, you can change all those `0,0,0`'s into `255,255,255`'s. If 70% is a bit much, go ahead and change the `.7`. And, for future reference check out this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2):

For me the filter/gradient approach didn't work (perhaps due to the existing CSS) so I have used `:before` pseudo styling trick instead:

```css
.eventBannerContainer {
    position: relative;
}
.eventBannerContainer:before {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
/* make any immediate child elements above our darkening mask */
.eventBannerContainer > * {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Since the default `display` for `::before` is `inline` it will not accept `width` and `height`.

Comment: Thanks @connexo, looks like I missed it when copying the relevant styles.

Comment: Position relative on child elements was the missing piece I needed

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Alex Price's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883980/3337038) answer I made an scss mixin:

```css
@function decToHex($dec) {
    $dec: round($dec);
    $hex: "0123456789ABCDEF";
    $first: (($dec - $dec % 16)/16)+1;
    $second: ($dec % 16)+1;
    @return str-slice($hex, $first, $first) + str-slice($hex, $second, $second);
}

@mixin darken-bg ($darkAmount) {
    $filterHex: decToHex(255 * $darkAmount);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, $darkAmount),rgba(0, 0, 0, $darkAmount));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, $darkAmount),rgba(0, 0, 0, $darkAmount));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, $darkAmount),rgba(0, 0, 0, $darkAmount));
    filter: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='##{$filterHex}000000', endColorstr='##{$filterHex}000000',GradientType=0 )");
}

/* usage */
.some-div {
    @include darken-bg(0.2);
}
```

decToHex based on [Pierpaolo Cira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33960236/3337038) answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried using background-blend-mode for this:

```html
 <div
    class="dark-background w-screen px-24"
    style="
      background-image: url('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevx.work%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2021%2F03%2FLOUNGE-01-1920x1024.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=bc89ea53d39a8da6df1ca59ed5daba3155d44fa3627e5071448aecd5da8be808&ipo=images');
      background-color: gray;
      background-blend-mode: multiply;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      height:100vh;
      width:100vh;
      color:white;
    "
  >Here is a text !! :) </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way I found

```
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
```