# make the color darker on hover without change the color

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to make the color of div darker on hover
I tried decrease the brightness using filter but this affect the text too

```css
:root{
    --Dark-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
}

#submit{
    background: var(--Dark-cyan);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#submit:hover{
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
 <div id="submit"> Add to Cart</div>
```

this is the result that I want:
[off hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwVMa.png)
[on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYI17.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to darken a background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208200/how-to-darken-a-background-using-css)

Comment: Why are you not using a proper `<button>`? A div is semantic nonsense (: and hence missing keyboard control, tabindex and any accessibility role.

Comment: @Andy I don't understand how this is related to my problem? if i used a button instead of a div this is going to solve it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an element's background-color a little darker using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297617/how-to-make-an-elements-background-color-a-little-darker-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `backdrop-filter` instead of filter :)
"Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent".

Unfortunately for firefox, this requires at this time: User must explicitly enable the feature

```css
:root {
    --Dark-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%, 0.9);
}

#submit {
    background: var(--Dark-cyan);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#submit:hover {
    backdrop-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="submit"> Add to Cart</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the answer=> "Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent"

Comment: Please add your answer to [the duplicate target question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208200/how-to-darken-a-background-using-css) rather than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `box-shadow: inset` with a large `spread-radius`

it doesn't affect the text color

```css
:root{
    --Dark-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
}

#submit{
    background: var(--Dark-cyan);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#submit:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 /*spread-radius:*/ 100px #33333377;
}
```

```html
 <div id="submit"> Add to Cart</div>
```

Comment: Please add your answer to [the duplicate target question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208200/how-to-darken-a-background-using-css) rather than this one.

Comment: thank you for sharing but I try to not specify the color manually

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can try reducing the alpha property from `rgba()`

Try like this:

```
.your-css-class:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 }
```

Comment: The OP is using `hsl()` so it would be more appropriate to suggest `hsla()`, or `hsl()` with the alpha channel argument.

Comment: thank you for sharing but this make it disappear not darker

Comment: I think then box-shadow:inset; shall do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the pseudo `::before` and `::afer` and some opacity on hover. Take a look at the snippet

```css
:root { --Dark-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%, 0.9) }

.btn, .btn::before, .btn::after { border-radius: 15px }

.btn {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700;
  height: fit-content; width: fit-content;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn::before, .btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
.btn::before { background-color: black }
.btn::after { transition: opacity 360ms 0ms ease-in-out }

.btn:hover::after { opacity: 0.6 }

#submit::after { background-color: var(--Dark-cyan) }
#remove::after { background-color: red }
```

```html
<div class="btn" id="submit">Add to Cart</div>
<div class="btn" id="remove">Remove from Cart</div>
```